# Simultaneous gesture recognition for specific gestures

Tags: swift, uigesturerecognizer

I'm trying to enable simultaneous gesture recognition but only for the `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` and `UIRotationGestureRecognizer` gestures. I don't want it to work for any other gestures. If I set the following property to true it allows all gestures to be recognized simultaneously, how can I limit it to just rotating and scaling?

```
func gestureRecognizer(UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Make sure your class implements `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate ...
```

---

Set the gesture's `delegate` to `self`

```
yourGesture.delegate = self
```

---

Add delegate function to your class

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    if (gestureRecognizer is UIPanGestureRecognizer || gestureRecognizer is UIRotationGestureRecognizer) {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to make yourself a UIGestureRecognizerDelegate

Comment: and don't forget to set yourGesture.delegate = self

Comment: @budidino I am adding the gestures on a SubClass of UIImageView. I have enabled userInteraction, set the delegate of both the gestures and still it wont call the delegate method.

Comment: @Skywalker I'm in the same boat (sub class of a `UIView` inside a `UIScrollView`): Added everything but the func is never called. Did you manage to fix it?

Answer (score -1):

any 2 cents for swift 5.1

// suppose You need to prefer pinch to pan:

```
//UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {

        if gestureRecognizer is UIPinchGestureRecognizer {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
```