# Swift/Spritekit UILongPressGestureRecognizer seems to ignore all other gestures while Pressed

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

first off, i am new to swift development.  i am learning and things are going mostly smoothly but i've come across this issue and can't seem to beat it down. i searched but there just isn't a lot of info out there.  the few questions relating to this issue on SO aren't helpful either (perhaps i just don't know the proper terms to search for..?)

anyway.

i have set up my gesture recognizers for swipes, taps and long presses.  they work fine.  the problem comes when i do the long press.  the long press is used to trigger player movement (technically it moves the background image(s)) it works, he animates and moves but while moving the system does not recognize any other gesture input.  the moment i let go of the long press the other recognizers function as they should.

in my GameViewController i added

```
skView.multipleTouchEnabled = true
```

but it had no affect.  it still doesn't seem to register the additional touch events while the long press is active.  my code is below.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    // gesture recognizer
    // swipe up
    let swipeUp:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(GameScene.handleSwipe(_:)))
    swipeUp.direction = .Up
    view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeUp)
    // swipe dn
    let swipeDn:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(GameScene.handleSwipe(_:)))
    swipeDn.direction = .Down
    view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDn)
    // swipe rt
    let swipeRt:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(GameScene.handleSwipe(_:)))
    swipeRt.direction = .Right
    view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRt)
    // swipe lt
    let swipeLt:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(GameScene.handleSwipe(_:)))
    swipeLt.direction = .Left
    view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLt)
    // tap
    let tapped:UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(GameScene.handleTap(_:)))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tapped)
    // long press
    let pressed:UILongPressGestureRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(GameScene.handlePress(_:)))
    pressed.minimumPressDuration = 0.1
    view.addGestureRecognizer(pressed)
}


// swipes
func handleSwipe(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    switch sender.direction {
    case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right:
        swipeRT = true
        print("swipe RIGHT")
    case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left:
        swipeLT = true
        print("swipe LEFT")
    case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Up:
        swipeUP = true
        print("swipe UP")
    case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Down:
        swipeDN = true
        print("swipe DOWN")
    default:
        print("nothing to see here")
    }
}
// taps
func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("tap")
}

func handlePress(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    if sender.state == .Began {
        theWAY()
    }
    if sender.state == .Ended {
        player.runAction(animIdle)
        moving = false
    }
}
```

i realize that there may be better/more efficient ways of achieving this.  i'm 100% open to suggestions and critique.  as i said, i'm new to this whole thing.  thanks for any help and i apologize if this runs afoul of the whole "search before you post" thing.  i did search, i promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` method `gestureRecognizer(_:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:)`.

See [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30829973/simultaneous-gesture-recognition-for-specific-gestures) for reference.

Comment: that did the trick. i, foolishly, hadn't added the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate to my class so it wasn't working at first.  i also had to set each gesture delegate as self.  i'm still coming to grips with how the whole delegate thing works.  confusing as heck for us beginners.

thanks!  i +1 but i don't have the rep points for it to show up yet.

Comment: @BuckRussell Good that you got it working, and no worries!