# iOS: recognize pinch gestures but not two finger pans?

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, uipinchgesturerecognizer

The goal is to only let pinch gestures get recognized if a two-finger pan is not in process.

This code allows both `pinchGesture` and two-finger `panGestures`, but they occur at the same time. This was based off [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30829973/simultaneous-gesture-recognition-for-specific-gestures) to use the `gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer)` function.

```
    // Handle two-finger pans
    let twoFingerPanRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(sceneViewPannedTwoFingers))
    twoFingerPanRecognizer.minimumNumberOfTouches = 2
    twoFingerPanRecognizer.maximumNumberOfTouches = 2
    twoFingerPanRecognizer.delegate = self
    sceneView.addGestureRecognizer(twoFingerPanRecognizer)

    // Handle pinches
    let pinchGesture = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(sceneViewPinched))
    pinchGesture.delegate = self
    sceneView.addGestureRecognizer(pinchGesture)

    func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
       if gestureRecognizer is UIPinchGestureRecognizer {
          return false
       } else {
          return true
       }
     }
```

This code allows two-finger pans, but pinches do not work at all.

```
    // Handle two-finger pans
    let twoFingerPanRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(sceneViewPannedTwoFingers))
    twoFingerPanRecognizer.minimumNumberOfTouches = 2
    twoFingerPanRecognizer.maximumNumberOfTouches = 2
    twoFingerPanRecognizer.delegate = self
    sceneView.addGestureRecognizer(twoFingerPanRecognizer)

    // Handle taps
    let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(sceneViewTapped))
    sceneView.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)

    // Handle pinches
    let pinchGesture = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(sceneViewPinched))
    pinchGesture.delegate = self
    pinchGesture.requireGestureRecognizerToFail(twoFingerPanRecognizer)
    sceneView.addGestureRecognizer(pinchGesture)

    func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
       return true
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to set only one pinch gesture recognizer?

Comment: @user3182143 sure. thanks!

Comment: you want to perform only one gesture at a time? either pinch or pan?

Comment: @NDoc there are other gestures like tap as well, not just pinch and pan. but yes, the goal is to only allow pinch or pan in this particular case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you try like this

```
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    if ((gestureRecognizer is UIPinchGestureRecognizer || gestureRecognizer is UIPanGestureRecognizer)
         && (otherGestureRecognizer is UIPinchGestureRecognizer || otherGestureRecognizer is UIPanGestureRecognizer))  {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: Does not work. Two-finger pans work, but pinches don't work at all.

Comment: Have you removed this line `requireGestureRecognizerToFail`, try my answer after removing the line.

Comment: In this case we are checking the two gesture that are simultaneously calling, if both are pinch and pan you doesn't want to them perform  simultaneously, so we have return false, and in other case true.